# reputation graph shows different y-axis when selecting negative reputation

Tags: bug

Normally when you're at the reputation grapth, it always shows the y-axis between 0-200:

[image]

But when you only select negative reputation, the y-axis changes to fill in the full 2 rep changes, I thought I found it looking silly to even show rep in decimals:

[image]

As shown above, this is only the case if there are really only one or more -2 reputations in the selected time window (added another screenshot for test case).

[image]

Comment: there're other cases where the auto-generated axis markers do silly stuff if the range they're given is too small.  Tehy've been reported enough times that I'm pretty sure the official answer comes down to "it's the 3rd party library we're using's fault, we're not patching it for them".